# How to prove "basic" identities in first order logic?

Tags: reference-request, logic

On the Wikipedia page for First-order logic, there is a list of [Provable Identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Provable_identities). Although they seem very basic, I can't find anyone giving a formal proof of them.

In particular, consider one direction of one of these identities:

$$\lnot \forall a. P(a) \to \exists b. \lnot P(b)$$

What are some strategies to prove this statement -- that is, how do I 'work' with the negation of a quantifier?

Comment: "Not for all $a$" implies what?  Here are a couple options: "for none of $a$," "for some of $a$," "there exists $a$ such that not..."  One proof strategy is to use a truth table.

Comment: @Lucky Using what deduction system?

Comment: You could use the method of analytic tableaux.

Comment: That Wikipedia article is fairly awful. I would advise you not to take it too seriously.

Comment: Your link is titled "Probable" and the URL is titled "Provable. There is a huge difference between provable and probable. Many probable things turn out to be unprovable, and many provable things are also improbable things.

Comment: It's helpful to know that "$\forall$" can be *defined* as "$\neg\exists\neg$", presuming classical logic.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\lnot \forall a, P(a) \implies \exists b : \lnot P(b) \\
\iff \\
\exists a : \lnot P(a) \implies \exists b : \lnot P(b) 
$$

QED

You should immediately see why this is true by understanding the meaning of the symbols.

For example, the first part says:

*not (for all $a$, $P(a)$)*, which if you can't negate that in English, can be rewritten:

$$\lnot (\bigwedge_{a \in A} P(a)) 
$$
which equals, using DeMorgan's :

$$\bigvee_{a \in A} \lnot P(a)
$$

In other words, converting that back to English, there exists a $b$ such that $\lnot P(b)$, then to math symbols, an implication of the above expression is:

$$
\exists b : \lnot P(b)
$$

QED